# Error using MCMC package Mathematica Via NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, markov-chains

I'm using this package https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-mcmc and am trying to evaluate the following:

```
MCMC[ -1040.3` (0.474` - (4300 10^(2/3) 43^(1/3) Sqrt[d] ((z 4300 NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[
a + b (1 + z) + c (1 + z)^2 + d (1 + z)^3 + r (1 + z)^4], {z, 0.44`, 10^6}]^2)/Sqrt[
a + 1.44` b + 2.0736` c + 2.9859839999999997` d + 
4.299816959999999` r])^(1/3))/z)^2, {{a, .7, .001, Real}, {b, 
0, .001, Real}, {c, 0, .001, Real}, {d, .3, .001 Real}, {r, .0, .001, Real}}, 100]
```

But it says:

> "The integrand 1/Sqrt[a+b(1+z)+c(1+z)^2+d(1+z)^3+r(1+z)^4] has \
>   evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the \
>   region with boundaries {{0.44,1000000}}"

any help or suggestions. **Thanks**

Comment: Replace Real by something like Range[0.7,0.3,0.01] where for each of the parameters you know that the argument of the Sqrt is positive ?

Comment: Thanks you I'l do that today and let you know how it went.

Comment: So I replaced real with Table[.001*n, {n, 0, 1000}] from 0 t o 1 and I still get the same error. Do you or anyone else have any other suggestions.

Comment: It seems that even with the starting values you give the argument of the Sqrt is not positive. On top of that ` {d, .3, .001 Real}` should read ` {d, .3, .001, Real}`